# How to properly split CSV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, csv, parsing

My csv file is

```
    1234567,AB,Client,S12345J,111 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS
    1234567,BC,Client,S12345J,111 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS
    1234567,CD,Client,S12345J,11 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS
    1234567,DF,Client,S12345J,856 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS
```

I have problem while using split on an CSV....
the regex command I use is **/(.*?,.*?),.*/**

```
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") { 
        var Allvalues = new FileReader();
        Allvalues.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
        Allvalues.onload = (f) => {
            this.splitted = f.target.result.split(/(.*?,.*?),.*/);
                                  }
```

I was expecting an array

```
          ["1234567,AB","1234567,BC"]
```

like

```
          0[] = "1234567,AB"
          1[] = "1234567,BC"
```

but I am getting

```
          ["", "1234567,AB", " ","1234567,BC",...]
```

like

```
          0[] = ""
          1[] = "1234567,AB"
          2[] = ""
          4[] = "1234567,BC"
```

can anyone help is rectifying it...Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here, but side note: Please _don't_ paste actual NRIC values into your question for privacy reasons.

Comment: Will there EVER be any commas in the actual values?

Comment: will keep in mind @TimBiegeleisen....And what Iam trying to do is split and take first two columns from the csv to an array

Comment: not getting you @mplungjan

Comment: This is what `split` does: any captures will be deposited into the resulting array as separators, in between the unmatched content. To get the format you desire, you need to map the split result, splitting individual lines (or better, `matchAll`, which would allow you proper parsing of CSV, with quotes and commas and all)

Comment: @JaganNathan will there EVER be a `"111, ABCD ABCEDE, ADDRESS"`  ?

Comment: no there won't be @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no comma will ever be in the data like `"111, ABCD ABCEDE, ADDRESS"`

then you can split and destruct on comma and do a reduce to get unique values

```js
const csv = `1234567,AB,Client,S12345J,111 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS
1234567,BC,Client,S12345J,111 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS
1234567,AB,Client,S12345J,11 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS
1234567,DF,Client,S12345J,856 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS`

const res = csv.split(/\n/).reduce((acc,line) => {
  const [a,b,c,d,e] = line.split(/,/)
  if (!acc.find(arr => arr[0] === a && arr[1] === b)) acc.push([a, b])
  return acc
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Older JS

```js
var csv = "1234567,AB,Client,S12345J,111 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS\n1234567,BC,Client,S12345J,111 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS\n1234567,AB,Client,S12345J,11 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS\n1234567,DF,Client,S12345J,856 ABCD ABCEDE ADDRESS";

var lines = csv.split(/\n/)
var res = []
for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
  var arr = lines[i].split(/,/);
  var found = false
  for (var j=0;j<res.length; j++) {
    if (res[j][0] === arr[0] && res[j][1] === arr[1]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) res.push([arr[0], arr[1]])
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Yes...it does split and returns the csv's first 2 columns but I am facing some trouble in finding the duplicates from the returned array..!

Comment: You did not mention any action on duplicates. What do you want to do? You can use a Set to make the array unique

Comment: Sorry for being confusing..!..
My full procedure is to Split and take the first 2 columns of the given csv to array and check for duplicates in that....You procedure returns an nested array so my previous code for checking the duplicates is not suitable for this..so I have to alter that...just asking if you got any idea for checking duplicates here..!!??

Comment: see update......

Comment: It works fine with a little changes for my side....Only downside is this code is written in newer version....so I am having compatibility issues...test application is working ..but the actual application rejects(mostly around => arrow function)

Comment: I made one compatible with IE10 or so

Comment: Sorry did not see the updated answer...will checkout the updated one too